# Groovy Elvis Operator

Tags: java, groovy, operators

Looking at the [Groovy Elvis Operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_elvis_operator) makes me relieved of the my wondering when using the ternary operator in java `String value = !oldvalue.isEmpty() ? oldvalue : newvalue` which I have to repeat a variable, but in groovy `def value = !oldvalue ?: newvalue` (*set the value to be the old value if the it is false else, set it to the new value*) which I have come to like so much. It really show one more of the sugars in [groovy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_%28programming_language%29) again

Forgive me if this is not right, But Why is the Groovy Elvis operator named [Elvis Presley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_Presley),

Just wondering

Comment: "But Why is the Groovy Elvis operator named Elvis Presley"  - hairstyle ;-)

Comment: What Groovy sees as "false" is not boolean false. Groovy is not Java and Java is not Groovy!

Comment: ?:  supposedly looks like Elvis's hairstyle....since the operator is so awesome I'll agree with them.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator

Comment: Did you notice that the ternary statement you wrote and your explanation of ?: are both wrong?

Answer (score 6):

In Groovy, it is called the Elvis operator because if you turn the `?:` 90 degrees clockwise/ to the right of your screen, the `?` looks like Elvis Presley's hair on top of his eyes `:` (the colon).

[image: Elvis operator sideways]